# Knockoutjs foreach binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have the following HTML in my KnockoutJS 2.3.0 app:

```
<div data-bind="foreach: chosenSurvey().questions">
    <pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($data.question, null, 2)"></pre>
    <label data-bind="text: $data.question_type"></label>
    <label data-bind="text: $data.question[0].content"></label>
    <div>
        <!-- ko if: question_type == 'input' -->
        <input type="text" />
        <!-- /ko -->
        <!-- ko if: question_type == 'textarea' -->
        <textarea></textarea>
        <!-- /ko -->
    </div>
```

I get the following output:

```
[
  {
    "content": "Where are you from?",
    "lang_id": 0
  },
  {
    "content": "¿De donde está?",
    "lang_id": 1
  }
]
input
```

And a console error:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: TypeError: Cannot read property 'content' of undefined;
Bindings value: text: $data.question[0].content
```

So the foreach seems fine. I can view the 'question' property using the  debugging technique. I can see the 'question_type' property being printed correctly. But no matter what I try to do, I can't access the [0]'th element of the question. Although the objects in the question array seem to print during debug, question[0] is always undefined when I try to access it directly.

My goal is to have a menu select for "Language" and I will show the questions in whatever language the user wants. So how should I be accessing one specific element of the question array?

The "if" statements aren't working either, so I'm wondering if I'm just doing this totally wrong to being with. Thanks!

Comment: If your `question` is an observablearray you need to write : `text: $data.question()[0].content`

Comment: uuuk. Yes 100%. I should have walked away and came back :)